# Auth0 embedded in iframe doesn't wok on Chrome but works on Firefox (Possible cookie issue?)

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, passport.js, auth0

I deployed my site on an Https server and opened the website on chrome. Everything was working. I use nextJs, passportjs, passport-auth0, and experssJs to handle authentication on the frontend. I also use the classic login experience offered by auth0. I have set sameSite =“none” and secure= true in my experssJs server so is inline with what chrome expects. I am running Version 92 of Chrome.

I then embedded the website in an iFrame. The website shows up correctly, I go to /login everything works but when login is successful and the /callback gets called it goes in an infinite loop and gives me the too many redirects error. I know this has to be an issue with the callback not being able to accurately read the cookies or that the cookies were just ignored by Chrome, because everything works perfectly in firefox(90 (64-bit)).

Any help with how I should get around the browser compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems that stopped the iframe to load.

1. Cross-domain cookies
2. Secure=True flag missing on individual cookie sets

---

**Cross-Domain Cookies:**
The way auth0 free plan works is that they provide you with an endpoint that the user navigates to. This endpoint then does the authentication and returns back to your website and provides you with some identifies in the response.
By default, the endpoint that Auth0 provides doesn't have the same domain name as your website, and to have a custom domain name you have to upgrade to the paid version of Auth0. Since the Auth0 login domain and the website domain were different the token was not stored correctly and it kept going in an infinite loop.

**Secure=True flag missing on individual cookie sets**:
Another thing I did was when I was storing the token returned back from Auth0, I would explicitly set the samesite=none and secure=true flags while storing the cookie.

Both the above combined fixed my issue.